# Android: Increment DB field via ContentValues

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I'm updating an item in a ListView via the `getContentResolver().update()` method, and I'd like to increment a 'views' field via a ContentValue, but can't figure out if this is possible.

I could do this with raw SQL `SET views = views + 1`, but setting a ContentValue, such as `cv.put("views", "views + 1")` results in the views field being set explicitly to "views + 1" rather than a number.

Any pointers on this on, or am I left to a more manual approach?

Thanks,

Paul

UPDATE:

I've gone back to using raw SQL to perform the update for now, and then manually notify the underlying CursorAdapter of the change via `getContentResolver().notifyChange()`.  Would still be great if I could figure out a way to do this directly via `getContentResolver().update()`, so if anyone has a way to do that, please post it here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My final solution to this was to use a custom `Uri` (along the lines of `...item/5/updateviews`) via the `ContentProvider` such that a call to `getContentResolver().update(customUri, ...)` passing this `Uri` tells my ContentProvider's overridden `update()` method to increment the view count for this item, thus avoiding the need to pass values to `update()` via it's `ContentValues` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the call API on my content provider as a way of sending raw/one-off SQL queries directly to the underlying SQLiteDatabase. It was easy enough.

Answer (score -1):

```
String key = "1";//some value where you want to update
int currentCount = 5;//the existing value of the count field

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("my_counter_field", currentCount + 1);
int updatedRows = database.update("my_table_name", values, "my_where_field = ?", new String[] {key});
```

something like that for using `ContentValues`.

a possibly simpler route may be:
`database.execSQL("UPDATE my_table_name SET my_counter_field = my_counter_field + 1 WHERE my_where_field = ?", new Object[] {key});`

or maybe even use a Trigger.  See this question to see if it suites your needs: [Use trigger for auto-increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401959/use-trigger-for-auto-increment)

Comment: How would I know the value of currentCount... isn't that the point of letting the SQL update command handle the increment?

Comment: you would need to get that beforehand :(

Comment: Ah... well that's not really incrementing then unfortunately.  Triggers won't work, as the increment is related to a user UI action, not a change to the table.  Thanks anyways.