# Classic issue: how to insert data to tables: books, authors, book_author?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I want to have 3 tables:

- books(id, title, auto increment(id))
- author(id, name, auto increment(id))
- book_author(book_id, author_id)

I want to make everything in one transaction, to make sure, that data will be inserted to  table only if everything is ok in all tables.

To insert anything to `book_author` I need id's, which I don't have.

Should I:

1. insert data to `books` table, make a select to get ID,
2. insert data to `author` table, make a select to get ID,
3. insert two `id`'s to `book_author`

?

Or maybe should I use triggers on insert? But is it a way to make trigger depend on two insert?

I that would help, I can say that I am trying to use python and sqlalchemy.

---

Second question maybe this will be important.... what if some database do not support autoincrement?

Comment: What is the context for this? Are you using Django or some other kind of framework?

Comment: @sean: I have a lot of stuff written in python, which extracts data from XMLs and try insert to database.

Comment: To better help you it would be good to know if you're using Django or some other kind of database ORM. This way we can better help you with your situation above.

Comment: This is what transactions are for; you commit after all the inserts are complete.

Comment: @Martijn: I am trying to use sqlalchemy. But should I make select to ask database about ID, which database gave to specific record?

Comment: @noisy: New ids are automatically assigned, and sqlalchemy takes care of that for you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: any example?

Comment: Use [`.flush()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.flush) on the session to have sequence ids assigned to your objects.

Answer (score 2):

SQLAlchemy Object Relation API does all legwork for you: adding records, transactions support, autoincrementing column values . So you don't need to bother with saving id for every object and creating records for every relation. The best way to show this with example:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, orm
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

__author__ = 'vvlad'

metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata = metadata


"""many-to-many relationship table"""
author_book = Table(
    'author_book', Base.metadata,
    Column('author_id',String(11),ForeignKey('author.id')),
    Column('book_id',Integer,ForeignKey('book.id')),
)

class Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'author'
    """SQLAlchemy's Sequence(name) for Column allows to have database agnostic autoincrement"""
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('author_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(length=255))
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(name=\"%s\",id=\"%s\")" % (self.__class__.__name__,self.name,self.id)


class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'book'

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('book_seq'),primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(length=255))
    """Defines many-to-many relations"""
    authors = relationship(Author,secondary=author_book,backref="books",collection_class=list)


    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(name=\"%s\",id=\"%s\")" % (self.__class__.__name__,self.name,self.id)




db = create_engine('sqlite:////temp/test_books.db',echo=True)

#making sure we are working with a fresh database
metadata.drop_all(db)
metadata.create_all(db)

sm = orm.sessionmaker(bind=db, autoflush=True, autocommit=True, expire_on_commit=True)
session = orm.scoped_session(sm)

"""associating authors with book"""
b1 = Book(name="Essential SQLAlchemy")
a1 = Author(name="Rick Copeland")
"""associating book with author"""
a1.books.append(b1)
b2 = Book(name="The Difference Engine")
gibson = Author(name="William Gibson")
b2.authors.append(gibson)
b2.authors.append(Author(name="Bruce Sterling"))

b3 = Book(name="Pattern Recognition")
b3.authors.append(gibson)
try:
    #here your transaction start
    #adding objects to session. SQLAlchemy will add all related objects into session too
    session.add(b2)
    session.add(a1)

    session.add(b3)
    #closing transaction
    session.commit()
#remember to put specific exceptions instead of broad exception clause
except:
    """if something went wrong - rolls back session (transaction)"""
    session.rollback()

print "Book info"
b3 = session.query(Book).filter(Book.name=="Essential SQLAlchemy").one()
print b3
for author in b3.authors:
    print author


aname = "William Gibson"
print "Books of author %s" % aname
for book in session.query(Book).join(author_book).join(Author).filter(Author.name==aname).all():
    print book
    for author in book.authors:
        print author
```

Answer (score 0):

Locating the ID of a record after creating it with a SELECT statement could be problematic if you have a large number of records being saved to the table. Using a trigger will allow you to easily reference the last record inserted. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/sql/trigger/mysql-trigger-after-insert.shtml).

Triggers will also help you with auto-incrementing the ID field of your table.  You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401959/use-trigger-for-auto-increment).