# Column value autoincrement depending on another column value Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I want to have one more column which will autoincrement depending on another column value:

```
ID    |   UserID   |  IDForUser
 1    |     4      |     1
 2    |     10     |     1
 3    |     4      |     2
 4    |     4      |     3
 5    |     10     |     2
 6    |     9      |     1
 7    |     9      |     2
```

Is that possible?

Comment: [Use trigger for auto-increment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2406528/6680611)

Answer (score 0):

The [built-in autoincrementing algorithm](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) does not work like this.

To compute the next `IDForUser` value, search for the largest existing value with the same `UserID` (or zero), and add one.
If you do not want to do this in your code, you must use a [trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER xxx
AFTER INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.IDForUser IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE MyTable
    SET IDForUser = IFNULL((SELECT MAX(IDForUser)
                            FROM MyTable
                            WHERE UserID = NEW.UserID), 0) + 1
    WHERE ID = NEW.ID;
END;
```